# svg dashed line hover only when mouse is over the path

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

i've got this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaroslav_cherednikov/6zya7w8j/2/) demo i built

and the problem is that hover effect already triggered when mouse reaches the view box. i would like it happen only when mouse is over the path of the line itself

CSS hover style:

```
svg:hover path#path-1{
   stroke: orange !important;
 }
```

the line was created with illustrator.

Comment: Just do #path-1:hover then but the stroke's pretty hard to hit.

Comment: thanks, it worked! but since the path so narrow is there a way to create some sort of container for this matter?

Comment: Sure, create an adjacent sibling path which is the same but with a larger stroke and is invisible. When you hover over the hidden path, change the stroke on the visible path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this directly and it will work i tested it

```
#path-1:hover{
   stroke: orange !important;
 }
```

line is so narrow hover will not directly work you have to check it closely.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/LSKhan/6zya7w8j/3/)